# about grounding on different circuit board

Tags: grounding

I got a STM32 development board, which is used to control another board for DDS output. The STM32 board send digital signal (TTL) for output control on the DDS chips. The STM32 board and the DDS board are powered in different supply. I wonder in this case, do I have connect the STM32 board and the DDS board in common ground so to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. TTL signals need a common ground reference. If you need isolation, you can optically couple the signals.

Comment: Thanks. The PCB for STM32 has a GND port, and it is power by USB connection to PC. The DDS board has a lead of GND, but the DDS is power by DC power suppler. Shall I simply connect the STM32 GND to the GND of the DDS chip?

Comment: Yup. In fact, the DC power supply is likely (hopefully) isolated, so connecting the two grounds together is no issue.

Comment: Thanks. How do I figure out if the DC power is isolated or not? What should be done if not?

Comment: Is it a wall wart DC supply? You'll be fine. Even if it isn't, your house wiring would have to be properly horrible for this to be an issue.